# Does Flutter support virtual or augmented reality?

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality, virtual-reality

I have to make an app that *uses* **virtual reality**, so should I drop the idea of using **Flutter**?

Answer (score 9):

yes as much as I have seen flutter does support AR,I have been following a [flutter developer](https://twitter.com/DiFraGM) on twitter he posts some cool AR stuff built with flutter here's a plugin [ARCore](https://pub.dev/packages/arcore_plugin) he has built for flutter.

here are some of sample AR videos from the developer himself

https://twitter.com/i/status/1123893412279791616

https://twitter.com/i/status/1129117305303175168

Comment: AR Core is SDK is available for both ios and android platforms and support for different development engines like Unity is available.

Answer (score 3):

> **Can I build 3D (OpenGL) apps with Flutter?**
>
> Today we don’t support for 3D via OpenGL ES or similar.We have ***long-term plans to expose an optimized 3D API***, but right now we’re focused on 2D.

https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#can-i-build-3d-opengl-apps-with-flutter

Answer (score 2):

there aren't any OpenGL bindings supported by flutter. Flutter is only a 2d only application.

https://flutter.io/faq/#can-i-build-3d-opengl-apps-with-flutter

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14591

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7053

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/179

I am not sure how VR would work at all on flutter.

Comment: I am sure that there will be plugins in the future.

Comment: OSX just depreciated Opengl. I would assume the only avenue for VR support will be Vulkan

Answer (score 2):

You can use google's ar core with flutter. Check out the [arcore_flutter_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/arcore_flutter_plugin#arcore_flutter_plugin) to work with ar in a flutter.
As of now, there aren't any packages that specifically target VR. But you can use ARKIT [arkit_flutter_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/arkit_plugin).

NOTE: ARCORE only works with android. And ARKIT only works with iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I recently created a Flutter plugin for AR that supports both Android and iOS by wrapping around ARCore and ARKit: https://pub.dev/packages/ar_flutter_plugin

The plugin is a work in progress, but it already supports collaborative AR and sharing content through Google's Cloud Anchor Service and a lot of other useful features